# How to control ACT LED on the PI 3B

Tags: pi-3

How do I use the ACT LED as a *Computer* power indicator on the PI 3 Model B? So that it turns off when I call `sudo halt` *once it's ready to be unplugged*. Kind of the way a computer has a power light and a AC Power light, and the one lights up whenever it's plugged in and the other one only when the Motherboard is powered on. Does the RPi have this concept?

I found this page: http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/controlling-pwr-act-leds-raspberry-pi, however he does not mention the 3B and while the file he refers to contains a bunch of options, which I will look into yet, writing to it has no effect, even though no error is thrown either. The dtparam does seem to work though.

Comment: A very similar question was asked at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44168/how-can-i-control-the-red-led-again/44177#44177.  The answer to your question is the same.

Comment: You can use the code on the linked answer.

Comment: I do not believe this is a strict duplicate, although I have posted my answer to the other question.