# How to read the status of the Power-LED on Raspberry Pi 3 with Python

Tags: python, pi-3, board-leds

How to read the status of the Power-LED (or the rainbow square - if you like that better) on Raspberry Pi 3 to detect an low-voltage-condition in a python script? Since the wiring of the Power-LED has changed since Raspberry Pi 2, it seems that GPIO 35 cannot longer be used for that purpose.

---

**Update:**

Since it seems to be non-trivial to detect a low-power-condition in code on Raspberry Pi 3, i solved it with a quick hardware hack. I soldered a wire between the Output of the APX803 (the power-monitoring device used on Pi 3) and GPIO26 and that way I can simply read GPIO26 to get the power status. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

On the B+ (and presumably Pi2) the "PWR" LED was connected to a GPIO pin as was the APX803 voltage monitor chip. This let the LED be controlled, and (presumably) let the Pi detect under-voltage.

The Pi3 "PWR" LED is directly connected to the APX803 but the APX803 is still connected to `PWR_LOW_N`. Unfortunately this is not documented and the schematic is incomplete, but is reputed to be on a port extender. Obviously the kernel can detect this, but again there appears to be no documentation. The only option seems to be exploring kernel sources.

[How can I control the red LED again](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44168/how-can-i-control-the-red-led-again/44177#44177) shows some info about the output status.

EDIT

---

I did a bit of digging, and was directed to https://github.com/6by9/rpi3-gpiovirtbuf/ I have tested on my Pi3, and it works. `rpi3-gpiovirtbuf g 135` produces output

```
Get state of 135 as 1
get_config dir input, active low (inverted), not terminated
```

which is active low and indicates Voltage is OK.

Admittedly this is not Python, but is very simple c and it would be possible to replicate.

Incidentally testing proved to be a challenge. For all the reports on this site of inadequate power supplies, I could not find one which was reliably low, and had to make a variable regulator.

The APX803 is open drain, so it should be possible to pull it low (and turn the LED off) with a program.