# raspberry v3.0, model B read red led status

Tags: gpio, pi-3, board-leds

How can I read the status of the on board red led in raspberry 3.0 model B? 
Thank you

Comment: The red LED is the power LED. If any code is running at all, you can assume that this LED is on.

Comment: In raspberry 3 when voltage in lower than 4.65 Voltage red led turns off. So I would like to detect voltage drops using the value of this LED

Comment: Ok, fair enough :)

Comment: In case GPIO 35 is confusing, it does not have a breakout pin but you can still read its state normally (using the BCM numbering).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
how can I read the status of this pin? As I have seen pi3 is not supporting detection of under-voltage using this pin. Am I wrong?

Comment: Please do not bother asking how to read the state of a GPIO on a Raspberry Pi.  This must have been regurgitated here and elsewhere on the internet *literally thousands of times*.   You might as well ask other people to do basic arithmetic for you ("Please, what is 3 + 5?") when there is a calculator in your hand.  **Use a search engine.**

Comment: I know how to read the state of a GPIO but GPIO 35 is not working so I asked if somebody else has tried something different

Comment: @goldilocks the supposed duplicate refers to Pi2. On the Pi3 the power is connected to a port expander. The question is a duplicate, see [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) which has some comments. There are other answers (how DO you find duplicates you know are there)

Comment: @Milliways You're right; [someone here implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251079/how-to-read-the-status-of-the-power-led-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-python) because of this it's not possible, although the end of your answer implies there is.  I don't see this as a duplicate of that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous.

If you want to determine the low voltage state, you can do this by reading the state through a mailbox interface. I have used the following c code:-

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54328/8697

Other code described in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/44177/8697 may also make it possible, but untested.

If you just want to read LED status `/sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/led1` seems to work; whether this also reflects the low voltage state is unknown (and AFAIK) undocumented. It is certainly possible to extinguish the LED by writing `0` to `brightness`.

Examination of the Pi3 circuitry (which differs from earlier models) seems to indicate that if the voltage is Low the LED will ALWAYS be off.

I have not explored what the impact of writing to `/sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/led1` is on the `rpi3-gpiovirtbuf`. GPIO can be input OR output (but who knows about the expander), so they may be incompatible functions.

Testing low voltage is a non-trivial task.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tested the code you suggested and unfortunately didn't work. It returns always "Get state of 135 as 0" despite there is or not under-voltage. Finally, I checked for the directory but there is no folder leds on /sys/device/platform

Comment: The code worked last time I tried it. As I stated testing low voltage is a non-trivial task. If you don't have led1 you don't have the latest 4.9.35 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Current kernels have the board LEDs in `/sys/device/platform/leds/leds`.  There are two; in each subdirectory you will find a `uevent` node with some information.  `led0` is evidently the green ACT light:

```
OF_NAME=act
OF_FULLNAME=/leds/act
OF_COMPATIBLE_N=0
```

And `led1` is the red PWR light:

```
OF_NAME=pwr
OF_FULLNAME=/leds/pwr
OF_COMPATIBLE_N=0
```

Note these names correspond to another sysfs directory, `/sys/firmware/devicetree/leds` -- but the information there does not look pertinent. However, in the same directory as `uevent` there is `brightness`, which apparently has a range of 0-255; normally when running it's 255.  Although that node is writable, trying to change the value has no effect.  But reading its state is obviously possible.