# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ got hot even in idle

Tags: power, power-management

My Raspberry Pi 3B Plus is running Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite. I only made `update`, `upgrade` and install `Apache2`.

It is connected to my home network with 1Gb Ethernet cable (no WiFi). Network traffic to the RPi is virtually 0 Mbps.

There is no heatsink installed.

My `htop` is the following:

[image: htop]

Which looks like it's almost free of any task.

However it is pretty hot. I can barely hold my finger on SoC and network chips. My thermal imager shows this:

[image: thermal img1]

[image: thermal img2]

(Note that the dark squares on the top image are reflective surfaces - which always looks dark on thermal images)

Highest temperature is 51°C with ambient 28°C.

I dont't have anything to measure current consumption, but I'd say that it is far more than normal. I remember that in idle my RPi 3B Plus was just warm a little bit.

- What can I do to debug this situation?
- What can I do to decrease power consumption?
- What else besides SoC can contribute to the power consumption?

Answer (score 6):

51 deg C is actually reasonably cool for a Pi3. My Pi4 regularly runs at over 60 deg C. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Can i decrease cpu frequency or anything else to make it cooler?

Comment: Why do you want it to run cooler?

Comment: It runs into PLA 3d printed case and if it run more cpu demanding task or will be laced into warmer environment it can damage the case.

Comment: I would suggest a 3d printed case that can be affected by heat is not appropriate for a Pi.

Comment: Besides, if this amount of energy is not necessary, why spend extra energy?

Comment: Is this correct that there is no way to reduce power consumption on RPi 3b+ ?

Comment: Even reducing consumption will get the CPU up to this temperature eventually. as said, its by design and is perfectly fine in open aired use. I would suggest insllalling even the tinies fan or an intake, exhaust system (intake bottom , exhaust top) for non mechanical cooling. Either way boxing it up is going to increase the temperature. Everything up to 90 degrees is "OK" in open air - otherwise, air movement is required for ambient cooling

Answer (score 3):

Like others said, 50°C is reasonable. I would not worry too much.

*However*, there are some things that you can do to decrease power consumption/temperature:

- disable some services which you don't need to lessen the load (e.g. I disabled bluetooth & wifi because I only use ethernet cable)
- [underclock](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md) with arm_freq in config.txt - maybe underclock your GPU as well?
- install a small (or big) heatsink
- update firmware as addition to updating your kernel (check [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) which does both)
- [disable LED lights](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70593/turning-off-leds-on-raspberry-pi-3)
- Disable HDMI if you don't need it
- blow at your RPI to decrease the temperature by a few degrees temporarily

Note: You can monitor the CPU temperatures with `vcgencmd measure_temp`. Makes all the blowing at your RPI more fun.

Comment: Additionally I was able to turn off HDMI which lowered the temperature by 3 degrees or so. By far it was the only thing I was able to spot any difference. What else did I try: lowered cpu freq to 400MHz, turned off WiFi and Bluetooth.

Comment: Right, I forgot about HDMI - I never close it since I use it a lot. Interesting, 3 degrees is quite a lot, it would be nice to see some tests if turning it off helps performance as well.

Answer (score 2):

My 3b+ feels a lot warmer than my plain old 3b: they are both idling most of the time. In fact they spend over 95% of their life idling. They are both housed in metal FLIRC cases. My point is, I don't want to pay for a heater: it's a waste of electricity. I just want a cool, efficient Raspberry Pi that I can leave on all the time and use as a git server for my home network. The other Pi is a DHCP and DNS server, so again is not taxed much at all. What makes the 3b+ run so much warmer than the 3b when idling?